# Text-to-speech is not working properly in android recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, text-to-speech

I created a vocabulary android app where we can listen the pronunciation of words and meaning by tapping on it. But it is not working properly, as it worked for first page only which appears it the beginning. On scrolling it stop working.

[image: Image of recyclerview]

here is the code of the activity which contain the recyclerview:

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_word_rv);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mDataList = mDatabaseHelper.getWordList("employment", "Name");
    ttsObject = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int i) {
            if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                result = ttsObject.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Feature Not Support in your Device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    mAdapter = new WordListAdapter(mDataList, this,ttsObject,result);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I just give a small piece of code which is related to this problem.

Here is the code of the recyclerview adapter:

public class WordListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
TextToSpeech ttsObject;

private List<WordListModel> mWordList;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private int result;

public WordListAdapter(TextToSpeech ttsObject, int result) {
    this.ttsObject = ttsObject;
    this.result = result;
}

public WordListAdapter(List<WordListModel> mWordList, Context context, TextToSpeech ttsObject, int result) {
    this.mWordList = mWordList;
    this.context = context;
    activity = (Activity)context;
    this.result = result;
    this.ttsObject = ttsObject;
}

@Override
public WordListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.word_list_layout,parent,false);

    return new WordListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final WordListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final WordListModel wordmeaning = mWordList.get(position);
    holder.mNameTv.setText(wordmeaning.getmWord());
    holder.mNameTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA){
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Feature Not Support in your Device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                ttsObject.speak(wordmeaning.getmWord(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.mMeaningTv.setText(wordmeaning.getmMeaning());
    holder.mMeaningTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA){
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Feature Not Support in your Device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                ttsObject.speak(wordmeaning.getmMeaning(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.mFavIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(context);

            try {
                if (wordmeaning.getIsFav().equals("false")){
                    boolean check = mydb.updateData("true",wordmeaning.getmWord(),wordmeaning.getDbTable());
                    if (check){
                        holder.mFavIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp);
                        wordmeaning.setIsFav("true");
                    }
                    Log.d("TAG",Boolean.toString(check));
                }else {
                    boolean check = mydb.updateData("false",wordmeaning.getmWord(),wordmeaning.getDbTable());
                    if (check){
                        holder.mFavIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp);
                        wordmeaning.setIsFav("false");
                    }
                    Log.d("TAG",Boolean.toString(check));
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("TAG",e.toString());
            }

        }
    });

    if (wordmeaning.getIsFav().equals("false")){
        holder.mFavIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp);
    }else {
        holder.mFavIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mWordList.size();
}
```

Comment: Make your Activity implement the `onClick` listener and handle the TTS interaction/lifecycle there - as well as the Database control. Abstract as much as you can away from the `RecyclerView.Adapter` so it only handles creating your views.